# Rigging a Robot Character

Tags: rigging

It's my first time getting into rigging and I'm trying to follow a tutorial on rigging using a robot character I designed. I'm at the part where I'm trying to set the armature with the body parenting using the automatic weights feature but it won't seem to work right off the bat like in the video. All the pieces of the robot are still separate. I tried joining them and doing it again and still no luck. The armature moves but no movement from the robot itself. What could I be doing wrong?

[image: rig example]

Comment: have you seen some kind of error message (on the top of the screen) after you tried to parent the mesh with the armature ?

Comment: hey lemon i haven't. As far as I know it acted as normal. It processed for a few seconds and then stopped as if it worked. I can try again and look for one. Maybe I'm missing a setting? Or the robot meshing is too complex?

Comment: The point is that the selected mesh in the screen capture has no vertex group... so it is not rigged. That's why I asked if the parenting succeed

Comment: I understand. Sorry Im still learning blender. As far as I know it didn't succeed. Let me try creating the vertex group.

Comment: No, Lee. The parenting may create it for you. You have probably an error while parenting. Common causes : doubled vertices or mirroring/symmetry problem.

Comment: Ok I see. Let me investigate this and I'll be sure to follow up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42542/discussion-between-lee-rosario-jr-and-lemon).